# NSStream write to socket gives no error with WiFi turned off. Why?

Tags: ios, iphone, sockets, nsstream

Good Day,

I am writing a custom controller on the iPhone for an application running on a PC.  I am using standard coding to set up & open a socket & write/receive data on my ios client.  All worked well until I went to an area with a weak wifi connection where either the iPhone or the PC lost its connection.  I added a test for a wifi connection on the iPhone using `Reachability` which works as expected.  I assumed that using one of the three possible error checking methods associated with `NSStream` would let me know if the remote end of the connection (i.e. the PC) was having a problem.

I started by sending an`[outputStream streamStatus]` message expecting to get an `NSStreamStatusError` code when I turned off the wifi adapter on the PC.  What I got was an `NSStreamStatusOpen` code.

Second try was to check for a -1 return code from `write: maxLength:`. Instead, this gave the number of bytes successfully sent (supposedly).

Third try was to explicitly see what code the `NSStream` delegate was receiving.  Most of the time it was `NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable` but never `NSStreamEventErrorOccurred`.

Does anyone know why? Is `NSStream` similar to `Reachability` (the older version) & is happy as long as the phone has a connection?

Thanks for any insights.

RB

Answer (score 2):

Occasionally, and especially with sockets, streams can experience errors that prevent further processing of stream data. Generally, errors indicate the absence of something at one end of a stream, such as the crash of a remote host or the deletion of a file being streamed. There is a little that a client of a stream can do when most errors occur except report the error to the user. Although a stream object that has reported an error can be queried for state before it is closed, it cannot be reused for read or write operations.

The `NSStream` and `NSOutputStream` classes inform you if an error occurred in several ways:

1.If the stream object is scheduled on a run loop, the object reports a `NSStreamEventErrorOccurred` event to its delegate in a `stream:handleEvent: message`.

2.At any time, the client can send a `streamStatus` message to a stream object and see if it returns `NSStreamStatusError`.

3.If you attempt to write to an `NSOutputStream` object by sending it `write:maxLength:` and it returns -1, a write error has occurred.

Once you have determined that a stream object experienced an error, you can query the object with a streamError message to get more information about the error (in the form of an NSError object). Next, inform the user about the error. Listing 1 shows how the delegate of a run loop-scheduled stream object might handle an error.

```
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)stream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode {
    NSLog(@"stream:handleEvent: is invoked...");

    switch(eventCode) {
        case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred:
        {
            NSError *theError = [stream streamError];
            NSAlert *theAlert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
            [theAlert setMessageText:@"Error reading stream!"];
            [theAlert setInformativeText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error %i: %@",
                [theError code], [theError localizedDescription]]];
            [theAlert addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];
            [theAlert beginSheetModalForWindow:[NSApp mainWindow]
                modalDelegate:self
                didEndSelector:@selector(alertDidEnd:returnCode:contextInfo:)
                contextInfo:nil];
            [stream close];
            [stream release];
            break;
        }
        // continued ....
    }
}
```

For more details: [Developer.Apple - Handling Stream Errors](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/HandlingStreamError.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002276-BCIDDFHF)

Comment: Ramshad: Thx. for the upload/link to the documentation.  As you can see from the question I tried all three of the suggested approaches but none of them gave me an error although I simulated " the crash of a remote host" by turning off its wifi connection.  Still none the wiser. RB